# How to use nginx image forward my projects port on docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I used different `docker-compose.yml` to up two sites
`nginx1` mapping `8080:80`
`nginx2` mapping `8081:80`
`nginx-proxy` forward `8080` to `80` and `8081` to `81`

The results `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8081` are fine, but `localhost:80` and `localhost:81` are not works, I don`t know why, and tried add containers to a common networks, not works too

I expect visit `localhost:80` and `localhost:81` to get right responses

##### nginx-proxy directory

```yaml
#docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  test-nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: test-nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 81:81
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - custom-nginx-net
networks:
  custom-nginx-net:
    external:
      name: nginx-net
```

```
# nginx.conf
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  300;
    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;
      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
      }
    }
    server {
      listen       81;
      server_name  localhost;
      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081;
      }
    }
}
```

##### nginx1

```yaml
#docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  test-nginx1:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: test-nginx1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - custom-nginx-net
networks:
  custom-nginx-net:
    external:
      name: nginx-net
```

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;

  keepalive_timeout  300;
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;

      location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
      }
  }
}
```

##### nginx2

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  test-nginx2:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: test-nginx2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - custom-nginx-net
networks:
  custom-nginx-net:
    external:
      name: nginx-net
```

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;

  keepalive_timeout  300;
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;

      location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose file for the ports section you have added like this

```
ports:
    - 8080:80
```

which means port 8080 will be mapped to port 80. here 8080 is the `host` port, this port you will be able to access in your machine, whereas port 80 is `container` port, this will not be accessible outside the container.

To access port 80 outside you need to map it to host port the similar way you did for port 8080 as shown below

```
ports:
    - 8080:80
    - 80:80
```

do the same thing for port 81 as well